# Setting a Buttons background programmatically from drawable folder incorrectly makes button background black

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I am creating buttons dyanmically for a gridview, however I want to apply a drawable background presented below. However the background is black, but on pressed appears correctly.

I have a button created called roundedge_button_dark.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="6dip" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#3f3f3f" android:endColor="#a6a6a6"  />                   
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="6dip" />
        <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>       
    </shape>
</item>  
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="6dip" /> 
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#0F0F0F" android:endColor="#000000" />            
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

I'm accessing said drawable button like so:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedge_button_dark);
```

The problem I have is that the image shows black, which is the end colour for the non state defined item; What am I missing or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff0000" />

        <solid android:color="#ffff00" />

        <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="2dp" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>

    </item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff0000" />

        <solid android:color="#FF6699" />

        <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="2dp" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>

    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this,
first create your drawable xml file for button states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Button Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button_click_effect"
        />
    <!-- Button Default Image-->
    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button"/>
</selector>
```

after that create rounded_button_click_effect.xml file in case of button click:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="6dip" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#3f3f3f" android:endColor="#a6a6a6"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and finally create rounded_button.xml file in case of default state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="6dip" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#0F0F0F" android:endColor="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```